# Align the points in polygon

Tags: polygon, array, alignment, footprint, move

I have two datasets consits of building footprints and point data.

Points are within the footprint but they are scattered. Is there any tool to align them perfectly within the polygon as pattern.

Attached screenshot is for quick reference

[image]

Comment: What is a perfect pattern?

Comment: any pattern within the polygon

Comment: But you have "any pattern" -- a random one. In order to code a specific pattern, you need to be able to describe it.

Comment: my requirement is that every point should be well aligned as array